# Como posso fazer login automático através de um get, com a biblioteca Request em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-request

**Código:**

```
import requests

username = 'admin'
password = 'admin'


headers = {'login': username,
           'password': password
          }

url = 'http://192.162.1.122/ISAPI/Event/notification/httpServers/ID'

r = requests.put(url, headers=headers)


print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

**Resultado:**

Relacionar o item

Document Error: Unauthorized

### Access Error: 401 -- Unauthorized

Authentication Error

Process finished with exit code 0

**Documentação:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo print da documentação isso é soap meu caro.

Comment: acredito que sim, a documentação falta dados, esta complicado

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde consegui conectar, agora ao problema é obter estava no XML, agora o problema e outro, obter os dados

conectei da seguinte forma http://usuario:senha@192.168........./ / / 
e enviei o xml correto